# How can I make HTML and CSS dropdown menu work properly?

Tags: html, css

I made my simple HTML and CSS dropdown mobile menu, but it doesn't work and i don't know why. I tried some solutions, but none of them worked. Navbar--buttons are not displaying, but why? How to make them display properly.

```
.button--navbar {
    display: none;
    width: 100vw;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    padding: 2vh;
    border-top: 3px solid #312783;
}
.button--dropdown:hover .button--navbar {
    display: block;
}
.button--dropdown {
    width: 100vw;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    padding: 2vh;
    border-top: 3px solid #312783;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #312783;
    outline: none;
    background-color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #E71A80;
    border-right: none;
    border-left: none;
    transition: 0.2s;
}



<img class="logo" src="assets/img/logo.svg">
<button class="button--dropdown">Menu</button>
<div class="navbar--buttons">
  <a href=""><div class="button--navbar">Diagnoza</div></a>
  <a href=""><div class="button--navbar">O nas</div></a>
  <a href=""><div class="button--navbar">Rezerwacje</div></a>
  <a href=""><div class="button--navbar">Cennik</div></a>
  <a href=""><div class="button--navbar borderbottom">Kontakt</div></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Visit this site, I hope you will find your answer to your problem. 
https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_dropdown_navbar

Answer (score 0):

Your `.button--dropdown` has no child elements, that's why `.button--dropdown:hover .button--navbar` not working. Move your `.navbar--buttons` under `.button--dropdown`:

```css
.button--navbar {
    display: none;
    width: 100vw;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    padding: 2vh;
    border-top: 3px solid #312783;
}
.button--dropdown:hover .button--navbar {
    display: block;
}
.button--dropdown .menu {
    width: 100vw;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    padding: 2vh;
    border-top: 3px solid #312783;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #312783;
    outline: none;
    background-color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #E71A80;
    border-right: none;
    border-left: none;
    transition: 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<div class="button--dropdown">
  <div class="menu">Menu</div>
  <div class="navbar--buttons">
  <a href=""><div class="button--navbar">Diagnoza</div></a>
  <a href=""><div class="button--navbar">O nas</div></a>
  <a href=""><div class="button--navbar">Rezerwacje</div></a>
  <a href=""><div class="button--navbar">Cennik</div></a>
  <a href=""><div class="button--navbar borderbottom">Kontakt</div></a>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It works properly on pc, but why it doesn't work on my phone safari?

Comment: How do you imagine `:hover` on phone? Hovering over your phone with hand? Either use JS to add classes on click or try using `:hover, :active {}`